# Aurelia: partially clickable translated text

Tags: aurelia, i18next

I want to show a text like this:

```
Filter has changed. Please [click here] to apply.
```

The `click here` part should be a link which triggers an action in Aurelia View Model.

Obviously, I can do that with a markup like this:

```
<div>
  Filter has changed. Please 
  <a click.delegate="doSomething()">click here</a> 
  to apply
</div>
```

Now, my challenge is that I want to translate the text (with `aurelia-i18n`). In different languages, the `click here` part can go in different spots in the sentence, so ideally the whole phrase should be one resource key.

But how do I inject the `click.delegate` then?

Comment: do you really want to let the user click manually to trigger translation of keys or do you have to? `doSomething` needs to be `doSomething ()` but i dont think this will solve your problem.

Comment: no, the translation should of course happen before the button click. `doSomething` will open a dialog box

Comment: Could this be a job for nesting? http://i18next.com/translate/nesting/ if not might be worth raising an issue on the repo https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues